# C# While TryParse

Tags: c#, tryparse

```
char typeClient = ' ';
bool clientValide = false;
while (!clientValide)
{
     Console.WriteLine("\nEntrez le type d'employé (c ou g) : ");
     clientValide = char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out typeClient);
     if (clientValide)
         typeClient = 'c';
}
```

I'd like to make it so it doesn't exit the while unless the char is 'g' or 'c'
help ! :)

Comment: Looks like trying to do things the long way around. Just validate the incoming string against the strings `"c"` and `"g"` (and using `ToLower()` if you want case insensitivity)

Answer (score 5):

```
string input;
do {
    Console.WriteLine("Entrez le type d'employé (c ou g):");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
} while (input != "c" && input != "g");

char typeClient = input[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

Is you use `Console.ReadLine`, the user has to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after pressing <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>g</kbd>. Use `ReadKey` instead so that the response is instantaneous:

```
bool valid = false;
while (!valid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nEntrez le type d'employé (c ou g) : ");
    var key = Console.ReadKey();
    switch (char.ToLower(key.KeyChar))
    {
        case 'c':
            // your processing
            valid = true;
            break;
        case 'g':
            // your processing
            valid = true;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid. Please try again.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, I think something like this will work well for you:

```
char typeClient = ' ';
while (typeClient != 'c' && typeClient != 'g')
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nEntrez le type d'employé (c ou g) : ");
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) { typeClient = line[0]; }
    else { typeClient = ' '; }
}
```

basically it reads the input into the `typeClient` variable when the user enters something so the loop will continue until they enter `g` or `c`.

Comment: That won't compile. `ReadLine` returns a `string`, not a `char`.

Comment: What if the user enters `gblahblah`?

Comment: @DrewNoakes: right you are, thanks, I've modified the code. And I'm not sitting in front of Visual Studio right now - just trying to help the OP get the idea.

Comment: It's better after your edit, but if the user presses enter without any other character, the `[0]` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @DrewNoakes, true enough. I think I've gotten it to where it needs to be now.

Comment: @bas now he has a +26 reps(+3 -2) for this ugly ansnwer. (BTW I haven't downvoted.  Yet.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `ConsoleKeyInfo` with `Console.ReadKey()` :

```
 ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
 do {
   Console.WriteLine("\nEntrez le type d'employé (c ou g) : ");
   keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
 } while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.C && keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.G);
```

Comment: English only, please.